# Is Vue suitable to build a website builder?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vue.js, drag-and-drop

I am looking to create a website builder using Vue. Think something like Wix, Squarespace and Webflow, where users can drop elements on the page (Div blocks, Containers, Sections etc.) and style those elements. One important requirement: The page layout can be 100% dynamic, so not just a fixed number of predefined layouts.

So basically the purpose of the application would be to let users manipulate the DOM. And this is where I get a little confused, because the Vue paradigm is obviously to make DOM manipulation data-driven.

I use Jquery UI drag and drop libraries, and these libraries assume you manipulate the DOM right away from Jquery (On drop -> Append html). So I’m looking for a little guidance on how to make this library adapt to the Vue way of DOM manipulation.

- Whenever I do it the Jquery way, the element is not recognised by the Vue instance, making it virtually impossible to do anything else with it. How can I make sure that elements I drop into the page are registered to the particular Vue component? I am thinking I need to somehow dynamically initialise a Vue component. So basically then every html element would become its own component. Is Vue designed for pages in which every element is a (simple) Vue component? How would this affect performance with hundreds of elements on the page?
- I would also need a way for people to move elements to different parent components whenever they change its DOM position. I am thinking I would then need to unregister and reregister a component in another parent. Is this possible and fast enough to maintain a smooth UI?
- I would need a way to dynamically assign styles to particular elements. I’m thinking I would dynamically assign a class from the data model using v-bind:style. Is this correct, and again, can I safely do this for every element on the page?

I’m very curious if such a challenge would be possible to achieve using Vue. Would be really nice if you guys could share your thoughts and point me into the right direction!

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Interesting project.  You could replace jQuery with this Vue llibrary which is based on Sortable.js https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable

Comment: You can try integrating [GrapesJS](https://github.com/artf/grapesjs) editor as Vue Component to build websites by drag and drop.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/FlowzPlatform/website-builder/blob/develop/src/views/GrapesComponent.vue) you will get great start on how to use this as a Vue Component